# why Is it not possible to perform fetch on fetched results controller from both init and viewDidLoad?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a table view controller that I have the deletion functionality in (I use core data too), and in the init method I added `[self.fetchedResultController performFetch:nil];` to fetch the results from the database because in another view controller I want to fetch those results.

And in the view did load I did another fetch with `[self.fetchedResultController performFetch:nil];`
because I wanted to perform a fetch also when the view was loaded...

I'm trying to figure out why when I added this method in both init and viewDidLoad I got an error while trying to delete an object that said:

```
CoreData: error: Serious application error.  Exception was caught during Core Data change processing.  This is usually a bug within an observer of NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification.  *** -[NSArray indexOfObject:inRange:]: range {0, 4} extends beyond bounds [0 .. 2] with userInfo (null)
2014-12-21 15:35:18.392 Treats[4153:582136] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[NSArray indexOfObject:inRange:]: range {0, 4} extends beyond bounds [0 .. 2]'
```

But when I removed one of them (docent mother which one) it worked fine and I could perform deletion...

Please help me understand this, thank!

my table view controller looks like this:

```
#import "StackTableViewController.h"
#import "Target.h"
#import "StackTableViewCell.h"
#import "HomeViewController.h"
#import "CoreDataStack.h"

@interface StackTableViewController () <NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultController;

@end

@implementation StackTableViewController

- (id)init {

    self = [super initWithNibName:@"StackTableViewController" bundle:nil];
    if (self) {
        // Do something
        [self.fetchedResultController performFetch:nil];
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:0 inSection:0];
        Target *current = [self.fetchedResultController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        self.currentTarget = current.body;
    }
    return self;
}


- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;

//    [self.fetchedResultController performFetch:nil];

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:0 inSection:0];

    Target *current = [self.fetchedResultController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    self.currentTarget = current.body;

}


- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews {

    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];

}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {

    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
}

// just to ignor a warning
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 44;
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    // Return the number of sections.
    return self.fetchedResultController.sections.count;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [self.fetchedResultController sections][section];
    return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
}




- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    Target *target = [self.fetchedResultController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    CoreDataStack *stack = [CoreDataStack defaultStack];

    [[stack managedObjectContext] deleteObject:target];

    [stack saveContext];

    if ([_delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(didDeleteObject)]) {
        [_delegate didDeleteObject];
    }

}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"StackTableViewCell";

    Target *target = [self.fetchedResultController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    StackTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if (!cell)
    {
        NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"StackTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [topLevelObjects objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    cell.cellLabel.text = target.body;

    cell.cellLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Candara-Bold" size:20];

    // Configure the cell...

    return cell;
}


- (NSFetchRequest *)targetsFetchRequest {

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Target"];
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"time" ascending:NO];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
    return fetchRequest;
}


- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultController {

    if (_fetchedResultController != nil) {
        return _fetchedResultController;
    }

    CoreDataStack *stack = [CoreDataStack defaultStack];

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [self targetsFetchRequest];

    _fetchedResultController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:stack.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];

    _fetchedResultController.delegate = self;

    return _fetchedResultController;

}


- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeSection:(id<NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo>)sectionInfo atIndex:(NSUInteger)sectionIndex forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type {

    switch (type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [self.tableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
            break;
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [self.tableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];

        default:
            break;
    }
}


- (void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {

    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
}


- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath {

    switch (type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
            break;
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
            break;
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
            [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];

        default:
            break;
    }
}

- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {

    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}
```

Comment: As far as I know, there is no reason you shouldn't call `performFetch` twice.  Can you post the code which initialises your FRC?  Is there any change to the data between the two calls?  Are you using the FRC delegate methods to update your tableView?

Comment: @pbasdf just added my tableview code :)

Comment: That all looks pretty standard.  At what point does the error kick in?

Comment: At the - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

Comment: At the saveContext method

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is, but why are you trying to perform the fetch twice? Why would that be necessary?

Comment: i tell you what I'm trying to do: I have a view controller that have a label, and I want to populate the label with the first object in the table view....so I created  delegate method as well to help me know when there was a deletion and update the label...so to initiate the stacktabkleviewcontroller I had to fetch the results in the init method...but then I also wanted to fetch the results in the view did load since I'm adding content to the table view from another view controller and I want to load the new objects when the view loaded...can I do it differently? it's not working properly..

Comment: I have a problem when I push to the table view and deleting the first object and then going back to the view controller the label is still the deleted object.. @TomHarrington

Comment: @JohnBigs - Once the FRC is initialised, it should keep track of any changes made to the data, so you shouldn't need to reperform the fetch.

Comment: @pbasdf got you, thanks allot